# Scrapy, сохранить полностью страницу, после выполнения всего джаваскрипта на странице

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, scrapy

Я хочу сохранить веб страницу (на этой странице работает джаваскрипт на клиенте и поэтому нужно его выполнить) с помощью скрапи.

```py
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835867/using-selenium-in-python-to-save-a-webpage-on-firefox"
```

Как мы можем это реализовать?

Насколько понимаю, в скрапи проект нужно добавить селениум ибо `scrapy splash` слишком тяжел для этой задачи, верно? Хотя и селениум не слишком легок, нужен и вебдрайвер и браузер установленный.

```
In [15]: from selenium import webdriver                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [16]: driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver")                                                                                                                                                          

In [17]: driver.get(url)                                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [18]: web_page_source = driver.page_source
```

и мы можем это сохранить в хтмл.
Только, как это интегрировать в скрапи и является ли скрапи+селениум проще для этой задачи, чем скрапи+сплеш и есть ли альтернативы?

В общем мой вопрос, как интегрировать селениум в скрапи проект для сохранения веб страницы.

```py
import os
from time import sleep

import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


class WebpageSaveSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "so"

    def start_requests(self):
        if not os.path.exists("so_dir"):
            os.makedirs("so_dir")
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            executable_path="./chromedriver", options=chrome_options
        )
        driver.get(
            "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1028597/scrapy-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80"
        )
        sleep(5)

        with open("so_dir/so.html", "w") as f:
            f.write(driver.page_source)

        driver.close()
```

Вот, например, моя попытка. Страницу оно сохраняет, это верно, но возвращает ошибку в консоль

```
lib64/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 87, in crawl
start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Как обновить этот код, чтобы не было ошибки?